# Convert x32 AT&T Assembly to Intel (Linux)

Tags: linux, assembly, type-conversion, intel, att

I have a quick ASM conversion question.

```
pop %ebx            
xor %eax, %eax      
movb %al, 7(%ebx)   
movl %ebx, 8(%ebx)  
movl %eax, 12(%ebx) 
xor %eax, %eax      
movb $11, %al       
leal 8(%ebx), %ecx  
leal 12(%ebx), %edx 
int $0x80
```

My try:

```
pop ebx
xor eax, eax
mov [ebx+7], al 
mov [ebx+8], ebx 
mov [ebx+12], eax
xor eax, eax
mov al, 11 
lea ecx, [ebx+8]
lea edx, [ebx+12]
int 80h
```

The main issue I'm having is the `7(%ebx)` (and simmilar). Does it actually mean `[ebx+7]`?

Comment: I'm getting an error with the program. I converted it directly, but the system call 11 (execve) is returning this:

`execve("\270\1", ["\270\1"], [/* 4 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`
It's supposed to be a /bin/sh shellcode

Comment: Update: Sorry, I fixed it. I am using jmp - pop - call trick and had some more instructions after the call.